# Separate GUI class and main class

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have 2 class .1 for GUI.1 from others.

LoginUser.java

```
package login;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import database.DatabaseConnection;


public class LoginUser{

    public int doLogin(String username, String password) throws Exception
    {
        int level =0;
        DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection con = databaseConnection.getConnection();

        String sql ="select level from staff where username=? and password=?";

        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement(sql);
        //no 1 and two refer to ? at String sql =...
        //Tukar String pada int
        ps.setString(1, username);
        //int iPassword = Integer.parseInt(password);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {

            level = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        //must close all connection
        rs.close();ps.close();con.close();
        return level; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test sama ada login berjaya atau tak?
        LoginUser lgn = new LoginUser();
        try {
            int level =lgn.doLogin("1008", "test123");

            System.out.println("Access Level : "+level);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Another one is for GUI class

LoginInterface.java

```
package login;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

import java.awt.Color;

import login.LoginUser;

public class LoginInterface {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField txtStaffID;
    private JPasswordField txtPassword;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void login() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoginInterface window = new LoginInterface();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public LoginInterface() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 678, 421);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblStaffId = new JLabel("Username :");
        lblStaffId.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblStaffId.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblStaffId.setBounds(108, 158, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblStaffId);

        txtStaffID = new JTextField();
        txtStaffID.setBounds(207, 160, 200, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtStaffID);
        txtStaffID.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password :");
        lblPassword.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblPassword.setBounds(108, 192, 101, 49);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPassword);

        JButton btnLogIn = new JButton("LOGIN");
        btnLogIn.setBackground(new Color(0, 206, 209));
        btnLogIn.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        btnLogIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                LoginUser lgn = new LoginUser();
                try {

                    String username =txtStaffID.getText();
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    String password = txtPassword.getText();
                    int level =lgn.doLogin(username, password);

                    if(level == 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You successfully login");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your password or username incorrect");
                    }

                    System.out.println("Access Level : "+level);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert your username and password");    
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnLogIn.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnLogIn.setBounds(283, 272, 113, 34);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogIn);

        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
        txtPassword.setBounds(207, 208, 200, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtPassword);

    }
}
```

I use PHPmyadmin and XAMPP as for database.Please help me :(

I cant run LoginInterface.I dont know why.Is something wrong on my eclipse luna?
Its only display for running LoginUser.java

Comment: Could you post the LoginUser.java code where you use the interface? That would help a lot with code analysis.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 2):

You never called `LoginInterface.login();` Just add it to your main method.

Comment: Can you describe bit about LoginInterface.login() ? What is .login refer to? Is it refer to package name?